# Hiding URL in fetch request on client-side in Next.js

Tags: javascript, next.js, fetch-api, form-submit

I have a simple contact form in Next.js that sends an email by using the [FormSubmit](https://formsubmit.co/) api when the submit button is clicked: The code for the `onSubmit` handler is as follows:

```
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const res = await fetch("https://formsubmit.co/ajax/your@email.com", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Accept: "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      name: "FormSubmit",
      message: "I'm from Devro LABS",
    }),
  })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => console.log(data))
    .catch((error) => console.log(error));
};
```

I want to hide the fetch request URL i.e., `https://formsubmit.co/ajax/your@email.com` on the client side, which is visible from the DevTools when the fetch request is made. I can't figure out how to do so in Next.js. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: That is impossible, because you are sending a internet request, and hiding that is just not possible. Even if you somehow managed to hide it from DevTools, they could just open a internet monitoring program and track the request.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is simply not possible

Comment: You can't hide the request, but you can use an [API route](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction) to mask the URL of the external service, by making the request against the API route from the client which would then make the actual request to the  third-party API.

Comment: @juliomalves Thanks mate! could you elaborate, possibly through a code example. If you do and write it as an answer, I could possibly accept it.

Comment: you can make it md5 or something

Answer (score 1):

While you can't hide the request made from the browser, you can use an API route to mask the URL of the external service.

Create an API route (let's say `/api/form-submit`) which calls `https://formsubmit.co/ajax/your@email.com`, and will act as a proxy.

```js
// /pages/api/form-submit
export default async function handler(req, res) {
    if (req.method !== "POST") {
        res.setHeader('Allow', ["POST"])
        return res.status(405).end(`Method ${req.method} Not Allowed`)
    }

    try {
        const res = await fetch("https://formsubmit.co/ajax/your@email.com", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: req.headers, // Headers passed from the client-side
            body: req.body // Body passed from the client-side
        })
        const data = await res.json()
        res.status(200).json(data)
    } catch(e) {
        res.status(500).end(`An error occurred: ${e}`)
    }
}
```

Then from the client-side, make a request against the newly created API route instead.

```js
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    await fetch("/api/form-submit", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                Accept: "application/json"
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                name: "FormSubmit",
                message: "I'm from Devro LABS"
            })
        })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => console.log(data))
        .catch((error) => console.log(error));
};
```

Comment: You will get an error due to the await inside a non-async function